# Date-wise repeat query

Tags: mysql, datetime

I have a table in my application which stores the user details. In those fields, user's saving their alert settings. I.e. we will alert the users on their saved date (s).

My table looks like

```
id   |    Username     |   name    |    alert_date            |     repeat_on
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
12   |    user_name    |   name    |  2013-08-12 00:00:00     |     30
15   |    user_nam2    |   name    |  2013-05-12 00:00:00     |     45
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

With a cronjob we are sending reminder email and SMS to the users. Like

```
select * from users where date(alert_date)=CURRENT_DATE
```

It's working fine but there is an option to repeat the alert according to "repeat_on" days. Like we have to repeat the alert on each '30' days (or whatever) from the alert_date. I am stuck here with the query.

Is this the correct structure of the table to do the same?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
SELECT * FROM users 
WHERE alert_date <= CURRENT_DATE AND DATE_ADD(alert_date, INTERVAL repeat_on DAY) >= CURRENT_DATE
```